# Convert any given function into an awaitable task

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

The goal of the following code is to cast any given function into an awaitable function. The idea is to use it when fetching the data from the db, giving the code the flexibility to either use the synchronous fetch functions (an imposition of my current ORM), or use the very same functions as async.

I am aware that there could be many things wrong with the concept behind code. By now I was just trying to get rid of the compiler errors so I can run the code and check the behavior. But of course I am open to discuss the concept beforehand, and if the whole idea behind it is wrong then use my time more efficiently looking for another solution.

```
async static void Main()
{
    // The following line gives a compiler error:
    // Error    1   The best overloaded method match for 'CastFuncToTask<int>(System.Func<int>)' has some invalid arguments 
    int task = await CastFuncToTask<int>(TestFunc(2));
}

private static Task<T> CastFuncToTask<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<T> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    T result = func.Invoke();
    taskCompletionSource.SetResult(result);
    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}

private static int TestFunc(int testInt) 
{
    return testInt * 2;
}
```

Comment: FWIW In .Net4.5 and above your `CastFuncToTask` can be simply written as  `return Task.FromResult(func());`

Comment: Is that approach any better of a standard `var result = await Task.Run(() => TestFunc(2));` ?

Comment: @Sinatr Yes. `Task.Run` unnecessarily starts new/existing thread to work when you know your current thread is simply going to wait. Just let your current thread to work and don't bother threadpool :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel OK so basically I am trying to reinvent the wheel and `return Task.FromResult(func());` does exactly what I am looking for. Good. The `Task.Run` "new thread" problem was what I was trying to avoid precisely, and I am under the impression that it is the "most visible" answer when searching "how to make custom function awaitable". I am glad to know there is a built-in function that does exactly what I need.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, "unnecessarily" - without starting synchronous method in separate thread there is no point in `await`, it still calls method synchronously (blocking caller thread, e.g. UI thread), so I am not really understand the point of `await Task.FromResult()`. It doesn't makes sense to me. I understand it could be used in method which suppose return `Task<bool>` and you can do some check `if(someconditionfail) return Task.FromResult(false);` instead even trying to call asynchronous methods.

Comment: @Sinatr If this method is consumed by UI thread, then `Task.Run` makes sense, Also I agree with you that `await Task.FromResult()` makes no sense. It could be simply `int task = func();`. To be clear, I don't understand the use case of the method here and why would OP need such.

Answer (score 24):

Running .NET 4.5, you can greatly simplify your code by doing:

```
int task = await Task.FromResult(TestFunc(2));
```

No need to wrap it yourself in a `TaskCompletionSource`.

> I am aware that there could be many things wrong with the concept
>   behind code.

If what you're trying to do is asynchronously query your database, this solution will definitely not help. It only artificially wraps your result in a `Task`. If you really want to query your database asynchronously, you need to use async methods provided by your database provider.

If you're using MySQL and looking for a driver that supports async, look into [*Dapper*](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)

Comment: I doupt that this will work. TestFunc will be evaluated prior to passing the result to `Task.FromResult` I think T.Rahgooy's answer is better. This would only work for parameterless functions: `Task.FromResult(TestFunc)`

Comment: @SchlaWiener That's exactly what his method is doing. He's invoking the method and wrapping it in a `Task`.

Comment: @Eser That was my original answer. It was mistakenly edited :)

Comment: @SchlaWiener both users YuvalItzchakov (in this answer) and SriramSakthivel (in the comments of the question) were pointing out that I was reinventing the wheel, but now you are saying that this built-in solution might not be suitable to my needs. Egos aside, I would like to know what is my best option.

Comment: @XavierPeña No ego in my answer. The only difference is that you invoke `TestFunc` internally inside your method, and I invoke it externally and pass the result to `Task.FromResult`.

Comment: @XavierPeña put your code in a WinForms application and see the result (also add some long running code to TestFunction). Both solutions will block your UI thread....

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I was talking about my ego :) (it would be nice to know that I was indeed not trying to reinvent the wheel, but I want to know what is best for my code regardless). So in your opinion using the customized cast would be better than using the built-in `Task.FromResult`?

Comment: @XavierPeña Although this isn't a *cast*, I would still advise you not to, since there isn't really a need. Read my edited answer, I'm not sure this will get you to what you really want to do.

Comment: The code above does the same as `var x = TestFunc(2); var result = await Task.FromResult(x);` I might be wrong but I am pretty sure TestFunc is evaluated before the threading happens.

Comment: @SchlaWiener There is no *threading* here. You're right, `TestFunc` is evaulated first, that's what I said. His example does exactly the same.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```cs
await Task.Run(() => obj.functionname());
```

Answer (score 2):

change it to

```
int task = await CastFuncToTask<int>(()=>TestFunc(2));
```

In your code the input provided for `CastFuncToTask` is an `int`(what `TestFunc` returns.) but it needs a delegate `Func<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

my method is this :

```
public Task<int> SetOffAsync()
{
    return Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    { 
        /*do something else*/
        return 42;
    });
}
```

and you can call this :

```
int var = await SetOffAsync();
```

Comment: As SchlaWiener was pointing out in another answer: "Task.Run is just a shortcut to Task.StartNew (which makes it more obvious that a new task is created.". And as I was saying: "Task.Run opens a new thread, thus not taking full advantage of the async-wait...".

Comment: i'm writing that at the same time

Answer (score 0):

With a windows forms application I confirmed that the first call is blocking the second isn't. So the best solution would be to use `Task.Run()` with a lambda expression.

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Text = "...";
        var result = await Task.FromResult(TestFunc(2));
        button1.Text = result.ToString();
    }

    private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button2.Text = "...";
        var result = await Task.Run(() => TestFunc(2));
        button2.Text = result.ToString();
    }

    private int TestFunc(int x)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return x;
    }
```

The compiler can not know that you don't want to evaluate TestFunc(2) but use it as a delegate and will just execute the method first and Task.FromResult will just wrap a `return value` in a Task. This is not what you want.

Comment: Wrapping a synchronous method with `Task.Run` to do IO bound work is rarely a good idea.

Comment: I agree that `Task.FromResult`seems to evaluate the function synchronously. But `Task.Run` opens a new thread, thus not taking full advantage of the async-wait... maybe there is no "good" solution to this problem.

Comment: @XavierPeña There is, use an async API. Which database are you using?

Comment: I think `Task.Run()` was designed for such situations. Yes you have an overhead but that's true for many await/async scenarios. `Task.Run` is just a shortcut to `Task.StartNew` (which makes it more obvious that a new task is created. There is a good article about that on msdn: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov well yes, that's true... using MySQL through NPoco. NPoco has async fetch but does not let the use of linq for this particular case (strangely it does when using the sync fetch). It's been a bit nightmerish to find a good-reliable-fast ORM... would be a bit of a hassle to switch again. Besides, my original question was generic on purpose, since there are potentially other cases in which this "awaitable cast" would be useful in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Below code  may help others:

Note: GenericMethod is parameter name which we are passing as Func with Input (T1) and output (T2) of generic  Type.
Task Factory will provide necessary access to run your task.

```
    public async Task<T2> GenericAsyncCall<T1, T2>(Func<T1, T2> GenericMethod, T1 input)
    {
        var _output = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            var output = GenericMethod.Invoke(input);
            return output;
        });

        return (T2)_output;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that CastFuncToTask runs synchronously.
if Func is parameterless you can do something like this:

`public static Task<T> ToTask(this Func<T> func) => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => func());`

Anyway we can play with TaskCompletionSource and return something we want regardless of the method. Lets say we have Action instead of Func

```
public static Task<string> ToTask(this Action action)    
{    TaskCompletionSource<string> taskCompletionSource = new 
           TaskCompletionSource<string>();
           string result = null;
           try
           {
               Task.Factory.StartNew(() => action());
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               result = ex.Message;
           }
           taskCompletionSource.SetResult(result);
           return taskCompletionSource.Task;
       }
```

Comment: [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/)